# Delphi TWebBrowser connect to a local device fails

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

Hello I have a very simple Twebbowser program. I want to access a device on my local network which is in the IP range 192.168.192.xxx.
I can reach the device via my chrome webbrowser but the browser in the program 
throws the error page:

"Can’t reach this page
Make sure the web address http://192.168.192.56 is correct 
Search for this site on Bing 
Refresh the page."

This is the Delphi code:

```
unit Main;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.OleCtrls, SHDocVw, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    txtAddress: TEdit;
    cmdLoad: TButton;
    WebBrowser1: TWebBrowser;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    cmdName: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure cmdLoadClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure cmdNameClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
   End;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm1 }



procedure TForm1.cmdLoadClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate(txtAddress.Text);
end;

procedure TForm1.cmdNameClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowser1.GoBack;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   WebBrowser1.Silent := True; //disable java script errors/windows...

end;

end.
```

Thanks for your help.
Ad

[image]

Comment: this has nothing to do with delphi. what do you get if you try to browse via internet explorer?

Comment: Show a screenshot of your chrome browser's address box so we can see the actual address

Comment: Have you tried `https` instead of `http`?

Comment: @whosrdaddy Works ok in the standard browser IE as well as Chrome see picture above, Thanks

Comment: @DavidHeffernan See picture above, Thanks

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, that also fails

Comment: Probably the issue relates to the authentication

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Hello David, what does that mean?

Comment: The dialog asking for username and password

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ok but why is the dialog not shown in the Delphi application?

Comment: If you know the username and password you can encode them in the URL

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Just tried http://username:password@192.168.192.56, that works in the browser but not in the application

Comment: @user741461 The error is saying it can't reach the device, not that it can't authenticate with it. Try using a packet sniffer like Wireshark or Fiddler to see if there is a difference between `TWebBrowser`'s network traffic and that of your other browser apps. `TWebBrowser` is a wrapper for IE, so it *should* work the same as the standalone IE browser.

Comment: Perhaps it's down to firewall configuration

Comment: @user741461 Ok I am hoing to try that, thanks!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Hi David, disabled the firewall and virus scanner, no result

Comment: Then perhaps the device is sniffing the user agent. As remy said, you should inspect the traffic.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is solved if I set a password to the device let's say '12345' I can reach the device's site with the URL http://12345:12345@192.168.192.56. The user name seems to be 
arbitrary for instance http://xxx:12345@192.168.192.56 would also work.
Thanks to everyone who contributed here, super!
Regards Ad